# Can't enable swapping in mac os x 10.8.3

Tags: macos, mac, memory, swap

some time ago a disabled swap. I need to enable it now and i was not managed to do it with help of

```
sudo launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist & reboot
```

my virtual memory properties:

```
sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.virtualMemory
{
    DisableEncryptedSwap = 0;
    UseEncryptedSwap = 1;
}
```

and swap usage is

```
sysctl vm.swapusage
vm.swapusage: total = 64.00M  used = 0.00M  free = 64.00M  (encrypted)
```

At this very moment i have 4 gb active memory used and 1 gb wired and 2 gb inactive. my mac book pro has 8gb RAM. Activity monitor shows that swap is not used( i mean swap = 0 bytes, page outs = 0 bytes)

Can anybody help me to enable swapping back?

**UPDATE:**
I just loaded all 8 gb that my mbp has and osx started to use swap file.

Comment: Are you sure it's not enabled? It won't actually be used until you run out of free memory (i.e. when wired+active+inactive reaches the machine's physical memory). Also, how did you disable it in the first place?

Comment: i unloaded dynamic_pager with "sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist"
U are right. i have loaded all 8gb and osx started to use swap file.
I was sure that osx will not wait untill i will use all of my memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched on swapping by

```
sudo launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist & reboot
```

As soon as I used all 8GB of memory, my not book's swap file started to grow. Profit!